# Contextual action bar does not overlay my toolbar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have created an activity and set  toolbar as the actionbar which i have positioned at the bottom.

Inside that activity, I have a listview that contain some data.

Problem is, when I long press a list item, contextual action bar appears at the top instead of overlaying my toolbar which is positioned at the bottom.

**my activity theme**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="myActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**my toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toorbar"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**my activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ToolBar toolbar =(ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}
```

What should i do to make CAB overlay my toolbar?

**EDIT**

This is `onCreateActionMode` method in my  class that handle long clicks

```
private class Selector implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_activity_menu,menu);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: why are u showing toolbar in onCreateActionMode using toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  ??

Comment: You need to remove that line

Comment: @RajeshJadav i only want the toolbar(now my actionbar) to be visible when one long press a list item. i then set it to `INVISIBLE` when an action has beentaken

Comment: Actually you do not need to do that. when you use windowActionModeOverlay to true. contectuctual actionbar replaces toolbar but you are showing toolbar in onCreateActionMode which is not required. when you click on done button in  contectuctual actionbar then toolbar automatically replaces contectuctual actionbar

Comment: @RajeshJadav i don't know why this CAB still think i have an actionbar at the top! imagine even after removing that `toolbar.setVisibliity` line. it stills shows at the top of my activity

Comment: @RajeshJadav have any other suggestion boss?

Comment: can you show your app screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my toolbar was at the bottom of the activity, solution was to make my own contextual action bar that will overlay it.

This project below gave me a head start.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-cab

Answer (score 51):

If you want the Contextual `ActionBar` overlap over `Toolbar` then use this

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Comment: i have tried teven removing `android namespace` but it still appears at the top instead of overlaying my toolbar at the bottom

Comment: **your edit is exactly what i have used in my question and still problem appears**

Comment: no Parent theme is different in edit. it is Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and also need to remove <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: problem still appears even after changing parent to `Theme.AppCompact.NoActionBar`

Comment: which Activity you are using AppCompatActivity?

Comment: my activity extends `ActionBarActivity`(by the way it is marked as depricated)

Comment: pls check by Extending AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity

Comment: that doesnt solve my problem. please see my **EDIT** on how i have implemented `oncreateactionmode`

Comment: It solves my issue exactly i removed android:windowActionModeOverlay to windowActionModeOverlay ,Thanks alot

Comment: @Rajesh It's have been a long time. I can see your answer has helped many people here solve the same problem so I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This worked For me,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

     </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this theme this may solve your problem.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

 </style>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. it only changes CAB's theme/style but **not moving it to bottom where my toolbar is located**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>

        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>

        <!-- required for toolbar in prelolipop -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        **<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>**

    </style>
```

use `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay>true</item>` for Contextual action bar to overlay toolbar. And remove if you have used 
`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`.  It worked for me.