# Contextual action bar not overlapping toolbar completely

Tags: android, toolbar, contextual-action-bar

I'm adding contextual action bar after long click of `RecyclerView` element. Problem is toolbar is still visible. Contextual action bar doesn't overlap completely.

Tried searching for info, but no or very little info found.

**My toolbar:**

[image]

**After adding contextual action bar:**

[image]

As you can see toolbar is still visible at the bottom.

**Theme im using:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**My toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#F7F8F9"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

**cab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_upload"
        android:title="Upload" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_upload_black_24dp" 
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_reboot" 
        android:title="Reboot" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp" 
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**This is how i'm starting Contextual action bar:**

```
startSupportActionMode(new android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode) {

    }
});
```

**My readings:**

[contextual action bar padding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444920/contextual-action-bar-padding-in-android)

[Contextual action bar does not overlay my toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755919/contextual-action-bar-does-not-overlay-my-toolbar)

Tried pretty much everything from questions above. None of them have helped.

P.S. Tried increasing/decreasing size of the toolbar, but visible line is still visible

**So how to make Contextual action bar overlap toolbar completely?**

Comment: That's it's theme i guess.

Comment: Actually tried changing themes, but its still the same

Comment: have you tried changing toolbar color? if not change and see if it takes new color or your theme color

Comment: Actually im changing colors then switching between windows, but yes it changes

Comment: use `<item name="actionModeBackground">your color</item>` in your style and styles.xml. it will overlay your toolbar completely.

Comment: @vrundpurohit I dont know why, but it worked. Manny thanks to you. Post it as an answer with details, I will accept it

Comment: sure. i am glad i could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">your_color</item>
```

in your `styles.xml` file,  it will overlay your toolbar completely.

Comment: This is only useful if you're willing to use the same color for both, the ActionMode-bar and your toolbar. I'm searching for a solution where the ActionBar's color stays dark gray and differs from the toolbar. Different colors are better for the user to recognize that he entered another mode. Still tried to set the height of the ActionBar via `styles.xml` to the same value as the toolbar height  - without effect... So, are there other solutions?